# Trying to use ORDER BY with average values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to sort values from an SQL table according to the averages of certain values.

My 'Exams' table looks like this:

```
+------------+------------+------+
| Exam       | Student_ID |Points|
+------------+------------+-------
| Math       |     3      | 20   |      
|Accounts I  |    23      | NULL | 
|Statistics  |    12      | 15   |
|Accounts II |     3      | 21   |
+------------+------------+------+
```

Here's the query I've attempted:

```
SELECT Student_ID FROM Exams GROUP BY Student_ID ORDER BY avg(POINTS) desc
```

My aim is to get the student ID of the student with the highest average rating, in this case, 3

Is my approach correct, or is there an error lurking in there? How will I be able to handle NULL values in the Points column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 options :

Don't count NULL's :

```
SELECT Student_ID, AVG(Points) AS apoints 
FROM Exam
WHERE Points IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Student_ID 
ORDER BY apoints DESC
```

Assume NULL is a number (in this case 0) :

```
SELECT Student_ID, AVG(COALESCE(Points,0)) AS apoints 
FROM Exam
GROUP BY Student_ID 
ORDER BY apoints DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate functions such as average require another column containing result of the aggregate function when combined with `GROUP BY`.

So try:

```
SELECT Student_ID, avg(POINTS) AS avg_points 
FROM Exams 
GROUP BY Student_ID 
ORDER BY avg_points desc
```

Comment: Do you have thoughts about how to deal with NULL's?